# Как найти строку, где объявляется переменная?

Tags: php, opencart

Установил на сайт платный шаблон [Лайтшоп](https://opencartforum.com/files/file/3741-laytshop-universalnyy-shablon-opencart/), возникла необходимость изменить нумерацию заказа. Она начинается с единицы, хочу задать свое значение. В шаблоне очень много файлом, знаю php совсем поверхностно, поэтому очень трудно найти нужный файл и строку, где можно сделать изменения. Уже понял как называется сама переменная. Пытался найти нужный файл путем поиска по названию переменной. Нашел около сотни файлов, в какой не смотрел, переменная там не объвляется. Есть ли какой-то способ изменить нужную переменную с моими знаниями php? Буду рад любому совету.

Comment: А точно она объявляется в php а не берется автоинкремент из бд?

Comment: Посмотрел все таблицы в бд, нет ничего похожего на номер заказа.

Comment: Вы были правы, значение берется из базы даных. Спасибо, очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас скачал опенкарт, посмотрел структуру, скорее всего номер заказа это invoice_no в таблице oc_order

файл **admin\model\sale\order.php**

кусок кода

```
if ($order_info && !$order_info['invoice_no']) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(invoice_no) AS invoice_no FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` WHERE invoice_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($order_info['invoice_prefix']) . "'");

        if ($query->row['invoice_no']) {
            $invoice_no = $query->row['invoice_no'] + 1;
        } else {
            $invoice_no = 1;
        }

        $this->db->query("UPDATE `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` SET invoice_no = '" . (int)$invoice_no . "', invoice_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($order_info['invoice_prefix']) . "' WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");

        return $order_info['invoice_prefix'] . $invoice_no;
    }
```

если имели ввиду не сам номер заказа а префикс, то он это **invoice_prefix** настраивается в конфиге сайта